# Onclick action in Magento adds to cart after initial action

Tags: magento, onclick

I am inserting a button on a Magento product page.
Code of this button is :
My Button

Clicking on it, the action is correct, but then somehow Magento tries to add the product to the cart.
My understanding is that buttons on product page are always interpreted as 'add to cart'.
What 'onclick' action could i add to cancel this 'add to cart' action ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You more than likely have nested `<form>` tags and onclick you're not only submitting your request but also submitting the "add to cart" form as well. Move your button outside of the `<form>` tag and this should correct your issue.  Keep in mind because many templates in Magento are nested through many `getChildHtml()` calls you may not see the <form

Hope this helps,

Robert